# Why is container_of not in glibc?

Tags: c, kernel, glibc, libc

Is there a technical reason why container_of() may not be acceptable in libc/glibc?

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: Is there a technical reason why `glib` or C++ `iostream` isn't included in glibc? Oh wait, the latter is....

Comment: Link to a definition of `container_of`.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinity of macros and functions that aren't in the C library -- there doesn't need to be a reason why any one of them isn't there, and the Linux kernel's container_of macro has limited utility. However, I don't think there's any *technical* reason why it couldn't be defined in stdlib.h as

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) (type*)((char*)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member))
```